# Java Spring jdbc sql server connection error

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

Trying to connect my Java Spring app on Tomcat to my sqlserver database with jdbc. 
Getting error:

> "Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection to the host BEN-790, named
>   instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException:
>   Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check
>   that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434. For SQL Server
>   2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running
>   on the host.)"

pom.xml

```
<!-- Server Connection -->

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Test -->
-<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.7</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


-<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0.FINAL</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
<artifactId>jtds</artifactId>

<version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
<version>4.0</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
-<build>
-<plugins>
-<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.9</version>
-<configuration>
-<additionalProjectnatures>
<projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
</additionalProjectnatures>

-<additionalBuildcommands>
<buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
</additionalBuildcommands>

<downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
<downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
</configuration>

</plugin>
-<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.1</version>
-<configuration>
<source>1.6</source>
<target>1.6</target>
<compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
<showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
<showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
</configuration>

</plugin>

-<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
+<configuration>
</plugin>

-<plugin>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
<version>4.0</version>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

my servlet-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<beans:beans xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven/>

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->

<resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->

-<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<beans:property value="/WEB-INF/views/" name="prefix"/>
<beans:property value=".jsp" name="suffix"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Enables us to use message.properties files -->
-<beans:bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">
<beans:property value="home" name="basename"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Enable connection to MS SQL -->
-<beans:bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
<beans:property value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" name="driverClassName"/>
<!-- <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/bens;instance=sqlexpress;useNTLMv2=true;domain=BEN-790"/> -->

<beans:property value="jdbc:sqlserver://BENS-790\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=TIGGER" name="url"/>
<beans:property value="COMPANY\bens" name="username"/>
<beans:property value="" name="password"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/> <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://COL-INFA:1433;databaseName=bens"/> <beans:property name="username" value="bens"/> <beans:property name="password" value="MyPwd"/> </beans:bean> -->

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.tigger"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have connection to the DB server from your machine. Are you able to connect a client tool to it ?

Comment: Yes, I can use MS SQL Server to SELECT data from the tables of the database. So I have my connection and Browser Service is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about change the connection bean for this?

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <!-- S2-Install-Start: INSERT DB SERVER HERE -->
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=MyDatabase;" />
        S2-Install-End:
        <property name="username" value="Stefana\Steffi" />
        S2-Install-Start: INSERT DB PASSWORD HERE
        <property name="password" value="" />
        S2-Install-End:
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 jpganz 18, that fixed it. I changed the class to "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" and the url to localhost:1433 and then it worked.